# What do we actually mean when we say Finite (Union/Intersection) or Arbitrary(Union/Intersection)?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

These two things - **Finite(Union/Intersection)** and **Arbitrary(Union/Intersection)**- we use so much in Topology - in fact the defining criteria are dependent upon these but after such long time spent with Topology I'm starting to feel I do not understand the difference at all.

$1.$ In a topology , **open** sets are closed under **arbitrary union** and **finite intersection**.

$2.$ **Colsed** sets are closed under **finite union** and **arbitrary intersection.**

$3.$`**Ideal** of sets are closed under **finite union.**

$4.$ Finite union of finite sets are finite.

Well when we say *finite union* of open sets , exactly at which point before $\infty$ do we stop intersecting$?$ For example,this set  $\Omega =\left\{\left(0,{1\over n}\right)\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a collection of open sets from $\mathbb R$ and I know intersection of a **finite** number of elements is again of the form $\{(0,{1\over m})\}$ and their **arbitrary** intersection is $\Phi$.

Now let us intersect only $k$ members of $\Omega.$ Now with that I intersect the $(k+1)$th element-again an open set ,intersect the $(k+2)$nd element and again get another,possibly smaller, open set. Now we continue this way , where do we stop to make sure we are not touching $\infty ?$

Same goes for the **closed sets**.

An **admissible ideal** $I$ contains all the singletons. Now take,say, $k$ of them ($k\lt \infty$) and get a $k$-ton member of $I$. Take union of $2$ such $k$-tons and get a $2k$-ton.Since the whole set in not contained in $I$,so the union cannot be **arbitrary.** It has to be finite.So,we have to stop somewhere.If we stop at the $p$th step,well that does not make sense 'cause the $(p+1)$th step is also valid.So, what's happening here?

I know my way of thinking must have some very stupid flaw in it.But I've been trying and failing to explain this to myself or say,put it into meaningful words. So please help me get this right and clear and understand the distinction clearly.

Thank you.

Comment: You can just stop anywhere to not touch $\infty$, because you will never reach it at some point. But really, $\bigcap_{i\in I} U_i$ means a set whose elements belong to all of $U_i$ and that's just it. It doesn't arise as some kind of limit as you take more and more intersections. In particular $I$ doesn't have to be countable

Comment: I suggest the readings on *Proof and Fundamentals by Ethan D. Bloch*, the author have clear explanation on family sets and its operation. There are also some comparison with $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$ (infinite series) and $\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_n$ and so on. The book is one of the best explanation and friendly on family sets and its operation than others I have seen.

Comment: @user160738: "*You can just stop anywhere *"-no,we can't. Because wherever I decide to get off the train I'll find that the next stoppage is also included in my journey.So, how do I make sure that I do not travel the entire planet?May be I could not express my thoughts properly but you did not understand my question.